# Not able to create snap with executable

Tags: bash, snap, ubuntu-core

I want to create a snap with snapcraft. I have no source code, just one ready to use executable (application/x-executable) and one shared library (.so). 
The user later on should simply type in "test1" into the bash and my program should start. I fail to create the snap. 
My folder structure:

`snapcraft-test --> snap --> test1, snapcraft.yaml, test.so`
Here is my snapcraft.yaml:

```
name: testsnap
version: '0.1'
summary: Single-line elevator pitch for your amazing snap
description: Some description

grade: devel
confinement: devmode

apps:
  test1:
    command: bin/test1

parts:
  test1:
    plugin: dump
    source: .
    stage-packages: [libsocketcan-dev]
```

and I get the following erros messages when I use `snapcraft cleanbuild`:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/build_testsnap/prime/bin/test1'
Stopping local:snapcraft-about-overremiss-gaynell
```

Comment: Is libsocketcan the .so that test1 depends on, or is it test.so?

Comment: @mpr it is test.so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without addressing the .so file (see my question above), I believe you'll need to play with the "organize" and "environment" options a bit:

```
name: testsnap
version: '0.1'
summary: Single-line elevator pitch for your amazing snap
description: Some description

grade: devel
confinement: devmode

apps:
  test1:
    command: usr/local/bin/test1
    environment:
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ${SNAP}/usr/local/lib

parts:
  test1:
    plugin: dump
    source: .
    stage-packages: [libsocketcan-dev]
    organize: 
      snap/test1 : usr/local/bin/test1
      snap/test.so : usr/local/lib/test.so
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This resolved my issue. As it seems I had some path errors.  My paths are snap/test1: bin/test1 (and so on). The "environment" resolved my .so part. I now simply "organize" the .so file into the lib folder and it works.